# CFC with mapping can't be found in Railo

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml, application.cfc

I am trying to get mappings to work

```
 ...
 this.mappings = {
    "/toolbox"  = ExpandPath(".") & "toolbox",
    "/models"   = ExpandPath(".") & "controllers/model",
    "/model"    = ExpandPath(".") & "controllers/model"  // hack, plural is correct
    };


setupApplication() {
 ...
// works
application.objCCFRO    = new controllers.model.ccfro();
application.objUtil     = new controllers.model.utils();

// Does not work
application.objCCFRO    = new models.ccfro();
application.objUtil     = new models.utils();
...
}
```

> invalid component definition, can't find models.ccfro at
>   railo.runtime.component.ComponentLoader.load(ComponentLoader.java:276):276
>   at
>   railo.runtime.component.ComponentLoader.loadComponent(ComponentLoader.java:39):39
>   at
>   railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.loadComponent(PageContextImpl.java:2784):2784
>   at
>   railo.runtime.functions.other.CreateObject.doComponent(CreateObject.java:178):178
>   at
>   railo.runtime.functions.other._CreateComponent.call(_CreateComponent.java:21):21
>   at
>   scorecard38.application_cfc$cf.udfCall(D:\railo\webapps\www\Scorecard38\Application.cfc:55):55
>   at railo.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:94):94

Note: ACF does not have this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make sure that the application name is changed when changing the mapping.